# C++ Simulate sequence of pulse trains

Tags: c++, simulation, modeling, pulse

I'm trying to model a pulse waveform in my application
and I need a way to keep track of the pulses so that I can repeat
their sequence. From the figure shown below, what I'd like to do is
simulate the first three pulses (pulse 1-3), then simulate pulse 4
immediately after pulse 3, and simulate pulse 5 immediately after 4.
Then repeat the whole sequence N times.

As shown in the diagram, I have the interval in seconds,
the start time of the first pulse in seconds, and the duration of
each pulse also in seconds. My application will be running real time
in a run loop where it will be executing at 1 Hz.

My question is, how do I keep track of all the pulses and make sure
they are all simulated with respect to each other? What I mean by simulated is,
for example I'd like to print a simple statement during the duration of the
1st three pulses, and the same for pulse 4 and 5. Can someone suggest a pseudo
algorithm at the very least for this operation?

[image]

Comment: `std::queue` of pulses.

Comment: Does the next pulse 1 start immediately after pulse 5 ?

Comment: Yes it does. There is no delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining the class `sequence` as follows, we can simply check activity of each pulse by `sequence::isActive`.
[**DEMO is here.**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/op4jN8DKJsC9sjSw)

```
class sequence
{    
    int period_;
    int start_;
    int end_;
    std::array<std::pair<int,int>, 5> pulses;

public:
    sequence(int start, int duration, int interval, int repeat) 
        : period_(2*interval+3*duration),
          start_(start),
          end_(start+repeat*period_),
          pulses
          {{
              {0                    , duration             }, // pulse 1
              {interval             , interval  +  duration}, // pulse 2
              {2*interval           , 2*interval+  duration}, // pulse 3
              {2*interval+  duration, 2*interval+2*duration}, // pulse 4
              {2*interval+2*duration, period_              }  // pulse 5
          }}
    {
        if(duration <= 0){
            throw std::runtime_error("Duration must be positive integer.");
        }

        if(interval < 0){
            throw std::runtime_error("Interval must be non negative integer.");
        }
    }

    bool isActive(int time, std::size_t idx) const
    {
        const auto& pulse = pulses[idx];

        // 0 for each start time of sequence (pulse 1)
        const auto refTime = (time - start_)%period_;

        return (pulse.first <= refTime) && (refTime < pulse.second) && (time < end_);
    }

    int getPeriod() const{
        return period_;
    }

    int getStartTime() const{
        return start_;
    }

    int getEndTime() const{
        return end_;
    }

    std::size_t getPulseNum() const{
        return pulses.size();
    }
};
```

Comment: I am using this code in an application that runs on a real time framework where it is running at 1 Hz. I have eliminated the for loop that simulates "time" because I get the current time every time the application is run. With that said, I am not sure what to enter in the main loop for "time". I am trying to enter a start time for the future to be able to start the sequence at a later time, but as soon as the main loop starts running, the sequence also starts. Any suggestions?

Comment: *I am using this code in an application*: very thx ! If we get the current time in second by `GetTickCount`, `std::chrono` or similar functions, we should enter itself to the first argument `time` of `isActive`. The first argument `start` of ctor of `sequence` is also to be real time in second. Does my answer make sense?

Comment: @DeeTee My quick implementation of real time simulation is [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/504r5KH3L2mTCkFg). I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response. I will test it out later this week and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood the problem correctly, the way I would do it is to use modulo-arithmetic, and characterize each pulse-train as a boolean function with a timestamp as a parameter to the function, e.g.:

```
// Returns true iff the pulse is present at the specified time
bool IsPulseActiveAtTime(long int theTime);
```

The benefit of doing it this way is that you can simulate an infinite series of pulses while using only a small, fixed amount of memory.  It also allows you to efficiently query what the expected state of each pulse-train was/will-be at any past/future time (i.e. not just as at the current time), should you need to do so.

Here's a simple demonstration program that prints out a ticker-tape of four pulses over the course of 100 simulated "seconds":

```
#include <stdio.h>

class PulseSequence
{
public:
   PulseSequence(long int startTime, long int duration, long int interval)
      : _startTime(startTime)
      , _duration(duration)
      , _interval(interval)
   {
      // empty
   }

   bool IsPulseActiveAtTime(long int theTime) const
   {
      if (theTime < _startTime) return false;
      return ((theTime-_startTime) % _interval) < _duration;
   }

private:
   const long int _startTime;  // time at which the first pulse starts
   const long int _duration;   // length of each pulse
   const long int _interval;   // difference between the start-time of one pulse and the start-time of the next
};

// Unit test/example
int main(int, char **)
{
   const int NUM_PULSE_SEQUENCES = 4;

   const PulseSequence sequences[NUM_PULSE_SEQUENCES] = {
      PulseSequence(0, 3, 5),
      PulseSequence(1, 2, 6),
      PulseSequence(3, 3, 4),
      PulseSequence(5, 1, 3),
   };

   for (long int curTime = 0; curTime < 100; curTime++)
   {
      printf("curTime=%02li: [", curTime);
      for (int i=0; i<NUM_PULSE_SEQUENCES; i++) putchar(sequences[i].IsPulseActiveAtTime(curTime)?('0'+i):' ');
      printf("]\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
$ ./a.out
curTime=00: [0   ]
curTime=01: [01  ]
curTime=02: [01  ]
curTime=03: [  2 ]
curTime=04: [  2 ]
curTime=05: [0 23]
curTime=06: [0   ]
curTime=07: [012 ]
curTime=08: [ 123]
curTime=09: [  2 ]
curTime=10: [0   ]
curTime=11: [0 23]
curTime=12: [0 2 ]
curTime=13: [ 12 ]
[...]
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time. Your answer looks legit, but it is a bit advanced for my current level of C++ proficiency. Is there a way you can briefly summarize what the class is doing and what the output shows? I'm having a hard time following along.

Comment: The output shows the pulses of the four PulseSequences in the array --- i.e. the first column shows a 0 whenever the first PulseSequence's pulse is "active" for the given second, or a space when it is not; the second column shows a 1 whenever the second PulseSequence's pulse is active for the given second, or a space when it is not, and so on.

Comment: The `putchar()` call inside the inner for-loop in main() decides whether to put a number or a space for a given `PulseSequence` based on whether the `PulseSequence` object's `IsPulseActiveAtTime()` method returned true or false.  (true == print a number; false == print a space)

Comment: The `PulseSequence` class takes the necessary parameters to define a pulse-train (start-time, interval, duration), and stores them as private member variables.  Then when `IsPulseActiveAtTime()` is called with a particular time-value (in seconds) as an argument, it plugs the time-value and the stored member variables into a formula to determine whether the pulse is supposed to be active at that time-value, and returns true if it should be active at that time, false if it should not be active at that time.

Comment: I guess it is not too clear from the way it looks in the diagram, but the way I'd really like for it to behave is to sequence through the pulses. So the sequence would be as follows: Pulse1, Pulse 2, Pulse3, Pulse4, Pulse5, then this sequence can repeat itself N times. When I look at the output, I see P1 starts before P0 stops. Then P0 repeats again before Pulse4 (in your example) is over.

Comment: You can set the parameters in the PulseSequence array to reflect how you want them to behave.

Comment: Yeah, I did that. I created 5 PulseSequences as follows: PulseSequence(0,20,30), PulseSequence(30,20,30),PulseSequence(60,20,30),PulseSequence(90,20,30), PulseSequence(120,20,30). Then I ran it for 270 seconds and on the output I noticed that 0 is still active at second 21, 0 and 1 still active at second 61, 0,1,2 still active at 81 and 0,1,2,3 still active at 111. And it appears that it would run infinitely as long as I let it. what i really want it to do is sequence through it N times as defined by the user. So if N was 2, repeat sequence {0,1,2,3,4}, in that order, only two times then stop.

Comment: Perhaps you want to add a "max num pulses" parameter or similar, then.  Part of programming is figuring out what you want to implement, and implementing it.

Comment: That seems like it would help clear up the repetition issue, but what about it overlapping with other pulses when it is not supposed to?

Comment: I added an input to the constructor called "max_pulse". I set it as a property _maxPulse. Then, I added a new clause to the return of IsPulseActiveAtTime as follows : ... &&(_theTime < ((_maxPulse)*_interval+_duration)). Depending on the other parameters, duration,interval and max_pulse, sometimes I get the outcome as specified by max_pulse, sometimes I don't. I would like to make it such that I always get the outcome as specified by max_pulse. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is max_pulse expected to do?

Comment: I am using it to keep track of a maximum number of active pulses.

Comment: Im also still having trouble understanding what the modulus interval operation is doing.